# Targeting and moving child elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently attempting to design a template for a Volusion platform e-commerce website. There is a table that is loaded on my category pages that I need to re-position using script. This would be simple enough to do if I was able to add a unique class to that table element, however the Volusion platform  has locked down the inner HTML of the page, allowing me to only change the template header/footer HTML.

The script needs to do the following:

1. Check if the current page is a category page.
2. Target the specified table
3. Append it to display before #MainForm

I have created a JS fiddle with all the relevant information:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lno034u8/1/

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Here is the JSFiddle HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <main id="content_area">
        <!--Table To Move --><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr><td>This Content Should display second, and should be colored blue</td></tr>
        </table><!-- / -->
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"></table>
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" border="0">
                            <tr><td>This Content Should display first</td></tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- Move Table To This Position --><!-- / -->
                        <form id="MainForm"></form>
                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"></table>
                    </td>    
                </tr>    
            </tbody>    
        </table>    
    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative:

```
$(function() {
     var table_to_move = $("#content_area").find("table").first();
     $("#content_area").find("form").before(table_to_move);
});
```

**EXAMPLE:**http://jsfiddle.net/nr5q1Lkz/

Answer (score 0):

Place this code after you determine you are on a category page:

```
$('#content_area').find('table').first().remove().clone().appendTo('#MainForm');
```

Comment: Looks good, but not working for some reason? I've updated the fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lno034u8/4/

Comment: Duh, because the fiddle page does not meet the url requiremnts :) My bad. will test on   actual site.

Comment: Change the css to `#MainForm table {background-color:blue;}` to change it to blue background.

Comment: Gary, this script targets and moves the correct table, but the .appendTo is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need the script to insert the table before #MainForm, not add it as a child element.

Comment: You can use the `.before` or `insertBefore` method instead of the `appendTo` method and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This simple function will do what you're asking for. It makes certain assumptions:

1. The colouring is taken care of by your existing CSS
2. The table that needs to be moved is the first table direct child of `content_area`

Code:

```
// Script I currently have that checks if the page is a category page.
$(function() {
     if (location.pathname.indexOf("-s/") != -1) {
         moveTable();
     }
    else {
    }
});
// END Script I currently have that checks if the page is a category page.
function moveTable(){
    $("#MainForm").before($("#content_area > table:first-of-type"));
}
```

Works on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lno034u8/5/)